# How to get xpath of invalid html?

Tags: xml, firefox, xpath, xidel

I am trying to extract xpath from html using xidel and recently encountered invalid html

i use firefox to get the xpath, but firefox automatically adds missing tags
so the xpath doesent match

can i stop firefox, or can you suggest a way to deal with this?

also is there someway of a reverse xpath? to get the xpath of some text?

Comment: By definition, XPath is valid only in the context of well-formed XML.  If the XML is not well-formed, then XPath can be ambiguous or unresolvable.  Your question does not have an answer.

Answer (score 0):

As Jim Garrison already mentioned: XPath is not going to work if your html is invalid. To answer to your second question: You can get the XPath of some text easily using an browser extention/addon. 
For Firefox you can for instance use [XPath Checker](https://addons.mozilla.org/En-uS/firefox/addon/xpath-checker/). 
I use [XPath Helper](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xpath-helper/hgimnogjllphhhkhlmebbmlgjoejdpjl?hl=en) on Chrome.


Just keep in mind that the results may be wrong when you are trying to get the XPath of a not well-formed html document.

Answer (score 0):

If the XML/HTML is invalid, Xidel will repair it, before applying the XPath.

Although it might repair it differently than Firefox. You can see how it was changed with:

```
xidel http://yourwebpage -e / --html
```

If you save that output and open it in Firefox, you can make the XPath for that.

Generally, the repairing might change intermediate tags, but it will probably keep classes and ids unchanged. You can thus replace some XPath like `/html/body/div[2]/div[@id="foo"]/p[1]/p/text()` with  `//div[@id="foo"]/p[1]/span/text()` or `//div[@id="foo"]//span[1]/text()`