# How to select elements which have descendant with empty text in xpath?

Tags: java, facebook, selenium, xpath

PAGE - facebook

I want print all friends online on the facebook (name, link to messenger), but I have a problem. I don't any idea. How can I get elements which contains two attributes:

1. `"//li[@class='_42fz']/a"`
2. `"class='_568-'" without text (if div of the class="_568-"/` is without text it means that friend is online).

My code is:

```
List<WebElement> friendElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//li[@class='_42fz']/a"));
```

But I want elements with only friends online.

Example of code:

```
<li id="js_pq" class="_42fz" data-id="101022398278367" aria-controls="js_po" aria-haspopup="true" aria-describedby="js_pp">
<a class="_55ln _qhr" href="https://web.facebook.com/messages/t/107022338465367" rel="ignore">
<div class="_55lp">
<div class="_55lq" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="_5bon">
<div class="_568z">
<div class="_568-">1d</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="_55lr">Jan Kowalski</div>
<div class="_55ls"/>
</div>
</a>
</li>
<li id="js_pq" class="_42fz" data-id="101012398278367" aria-controls="js_po" aria-haspopup="true" aria-describedby="js_pp">
<a class="_55ln _qhr" href="https://web.facebook.com/messages/t/290222338565367" rel="ignore">
<div class="_55lp">
<div class="_55lq" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="_5bon">
<div class="_568z">
<div class="_568-"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="_55lr">Kowalski Jan</div>
<div class="_55ls"/>
</div>
</a>
</li>
```

And in this case my program must get friend name and href to messenger from the second li, because div of class `_568-` is without text, it means that this friend is online. If this div has text for example `<div class="_568-">1d</div>` it means that friend isn't online.

Comment: Please include the HTML that contains the elements that you are trying to identify via XPath.

Comment: This is a facebook and I want get name and href (link to messenger) for only friends online.

Comment: Please make your question self-contained by providing the structure of your input document. You can't expect us to go and research it elsewhere.

Comment: Post the HTML here and properly format it. Your pastebin may go away in the future and will make this question useless.

Comment: I again edited my post and paste HTML structure now.

Answer (score 0):

The html snippet that you pasted is invalid XML, so [YMMV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32978944/how-to-get-xpath-of-invalid-html), but this should select what you are looking for:

```
//li[@class='_42fz']//div[@class='_568-'][not(text())]/../../../../../a/@href
```

or more elegant:

```
//li[@class='_42fz'][descendant::div[@class='_568-'][not(text())]]/a/@href
```

[DEMO](http://www.videlibri.de/cgi-bin/xidelcgi?compatibility=Enable%20all%20extensions&data=%3Chtml%3E%3Cbody%3E%0A%3Cli%20id%3D%22js_pq%22%20class%3D%22_42fz%22%20data-id%3D%22101022398278367%22%20aria-controls%3D%22js_po%22%20aria-haspopup%3D%22true%22%20aria-describedby%3D%22js_pp%22%3E%0A%3Ca%20class%3D%22_55ln%20_qhr%22%20href%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Fweb.facebook.com%2Fmessages%2Ft%2F107022338465367%22%20rel%3D%22ignore%22%3E%0A%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22_55lp%22%3E%0A%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22_55lq%22%20aria-hidden%3D%22true%22%3E%0A%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22_5bon%22%3E%0A%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22_568z%22%3E%0A%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22_568-%22%3E1d%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22_55lr%22%3EJan%20Kowalski%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22_55ls%22%2F%3E%0A%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%3C%2Fa%3E%0A%3C%2Fli%3E%0A%3Cli%20id%3D%22js_pq%22%20class%3D%22_42fz%22%20data-id%3D%22101012398278367%22%20aria-controls%3D%22js_po%22%20aria-haspopup%3D%22true%22%20aria-describedby%3D%22js_pp%22%3E%0A%3Ca%20class%3D%22_55ln%20_qhr%22%20href%3D%22https%3A%2F%2Fweb.facebook.com%2Fmessages%2Ft%2F290222338565367%22%20rel%3D%22ignore%22%3E%0A%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22_55lp%22%3E%0A%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22_55lq%22%20aria-hidden%3D%22true%22%3E%0A%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22_5bon%22%3E%0A%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22_568z%22%3E%0A%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22_568-%22%3E%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22_55lr%22%3EKowalski%20Jan%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%3Cdiv%20class%3D%22_55ls%22%2F%3E%0A%3C%2Fdiv%3E%0A%3C%2Fa%3E%0A%3C%2Fli%3E%0A%3C%2Fbody%3E%3C%2Fhtml%3E&extract=%2F%2Fli[%40class%3D%27_42fz%27][descendant%3A%3Adiv[%40class%3D%27_568-%27][not(text())]]%2Fa%2F%40href&extract-kind=auto&printed-node-format=text&output-format=adhoc&input-format=html&dot-notation=unambiguous)

Comment: @PL2000PL if you find the answer helpful, please accept it. Also, to better understand and participate to the community, read https://stackoverflow.com/tour